# iOS : fastest method to encode data in base64

Tags: ios, performance, encoding, base64

I'm looking for the fastest solution to encode an UIImage to a base64 string.
Also I'm wondering if the built-in solution provided by apple to convert an UIImage to NSData  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, quality) is the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [article](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour), a 5.3MB image (JPEG) file took < 50ms to encode, and about 140ms to decode using the base64. you can get the library code [here](https://github.com/mikeho/QSUtilities)

Comment: This saved my day, everybody who deals with large data and trying to encode it to Bas64 must use this implementation.